# Invoke a scalar function from python

Tags: python, sql-server, user-defined-functions, pyodbc

I see a lot of info about how to invoke a stored procedure to return, say, the key of a record that was inserted from Python to an SQL table using the `fetchval()` function.

However, I would like to invoke an SQL UDF.

The SQL is

```
ALTER FUNCTION udf_get_gleif_last_entity_lei
(

)
RETURNS nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @last_lei nvarchar(500)

    SELECT @last_lei = LEI FROM dbo.gleif_level1_entities WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM dbo.gleif_level1_entities);

    RETURN @last_lei
END
```

I can confirm this works by invoking it through a query window:

```
declare @result nvarchar(500)
exec @result = dbo.udf_get_gleif_last_entity_lei
print(@result)
```

Now I want to invoke this through python.  I thought it would work the same way as invoking a stored procedure:

```
[conn, cursor] = init_connection(server_name, db_name)
sql_str = "exec dbo.udf_get_gleif_last_entity_lei"
return_value = cursor.execute(sql_str).fetchval()
print("return_value = ", return_value)
```

Unfortunately that doesn't want to work.   It errors on the `cursor.execute()` command.

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

This makes me think that UDFs must be executed a different way.  Or maybe I change this to a regular stored procedure.  I can make that work.  Anyway:  Can pyodbc invoke UDFs?  If so, how?

Addendum: Yes. This definitely works when I change the UDF to a stored procedure.

Comment: Have you tried treating it like a select statement with a single row and a single column, i.e.: `select [MyResult] = dbo.udf_get_gleif_last_entity_lei();`?